# How to insert app-level constants into a django template

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a constant defined in my `models.py` as `NUM_IMAGES` and I want to access that in a template within the same app. How would I go about doing this? I certainly don't want to put it in the project's `settings.py`, exposing it to the entire project, nor do I particularly want to expose all settings values to the app as this might hurt modularity. So then, how would I go about referencing my `NUM_IMAGES` in a template, say `detail.html`?

Comment: pass it in the context in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily expose your constants to view by just wrapping them in context.
so if you want to access NUM_IMAGES in view 
first import it into views.py file

```
from models import NUM_IMAGES
```

then pass it to required view

```
def myview(request):
    #something to do
    return render( request,'app/page.html',{'NUM_IMAGES':NUM_IMAGES})
```